# SQL Query to list the contents of all the tables from the database

Tags: mysql, database

I wrote a PHP script to list all the tables present in the database using a query

$query = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbName";

Now, i wanted to know what sql query can be use to list the "contents" of all the tables from the database simultaneously to display it and then store it in a file.

Thanks ahead of time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mysqldump to dump all the data in the database. Else you can run for look on all the table names and then use select * from x; to get all the data from the table name x which you retrieved earlier.

Comment: Thanks Neo. but i want x to be called for all the tables in the database.. that's what i asked in question.

Comment: you can use a foreach loop in php. You can do something like:
      foreach ($results as $table_name)
         $query = "select * from $table_name";
         ......

Answer (score 0):

IF what you want is to backup your database and restore it check out this link

[MYSQL backup and restore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-and-recovery.html)

and you can use this command to create a backup of your databse

[MYSQLDUMP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)